# How to add a Row to a Grid from a form using Extjs?

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs 4.2.0 .I am trying to add a Row in a Grid from a TextField.What is the easiest way to do that.
Here i am using moving row from GridToGrid.Add Row button will add a row to grid one from hardCoded model values.But instead i need to add from the input text fields.

Comment: Some code to show your effort so far?

Answer (score 0):

Check this . Here you can add new records to grid as well as edit existing records by loading them in form.

http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/writer/writer.html